# RESTful API design need validation

Tags: restful-url

I want to develop restful API related to user authentication. please suggest if my URL designs looks ok. as a background information, these API use an LDAP directory such as microsoft AD.

1. user registration
   POST /auth/register
   payload : {username: "", password: ""}
2. user login

POST /auth/login

payload : {username: "", password: ""}

3. password change

PUT /auth/password_reset

payload : {username: "", old_password: "", new_password:""}

4. deactivate user
   DELETE /auth/de_activate/{user_name}
5. activate a user

PUT /auth/de_activate/{user_name}

I do understand that I am using verbs in the URL. However, since these APIs create some resource [register API] as well as perform some actions [login api], I went ahead with the URLS above. I would appreciate any inputs through.

Regards
Prasad Katti

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes I would make. I know that you know already that the URL paths should be nouns and your verbs should be GET, POST, DELETE, etc. to indicate that you want to view, create or delete a resource.

Instead of:
`POST /auth/register`  do `POST /registrations`

Instead of:

`POST auth/login`  do  `POST /logins` or `POST sessions`

Your password reset route is okay, but I don't believe the action matches the resource.

Instead of:

`PUT auth/password_reset`  do  `POST /password_resets`
And yes, PUT actions are supposed to update or replace the resource, but what other resources do you have that require you to send the old and new values? The one above is still accurate, since you are creating a "password reset" which sets off a workflow of actions that may require people to check their email and click a link, but I think that doing `PUT /passwords` is misleading due to the payload that is required.

Instead of:

`DELETE /auth/de_activate/{username}`  do  `DELETE /users/{username}` or `DELETE /users/{userId}` or even `PUT /users/{username}` with `{"active": false}`. Personally, I think that hard vs soft deletes should be transparent through your API though.

And instead of:

`PUT /auth/de_activate/{username}`  do  `PUT /users/{username}` with `{"active": true}` or `POST /users/{username}/reactivations`.

The purpose of RESTful standards is to make a consistent and predictable API for clients. All it is really is a set of guidelines. It's not super-strict or anything so ultimately it's left up to your best judgement. These are just the adjustments I would make.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. The reason I introduced the "auth" phrase was to club all these actions under one context.

Comment: Is it not possible to do that without changing the path? I don't think your URL should reflect your code implementation.